# WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wso2

I've managed to install and run the emm server on an Amazon EC2 instance. However, I am not able to access the emm or carbon console on a web browser. Is there any configuration settings that I have missed out?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? If so please post it.

Comment: Have you opened relevant ports for inbound traffic? If you are using default server configurations, you may want to open 9443 and 9763 ports.

Comment: "Is there any configuration settings that I have missed out?" How could we possibly know this? You haven't provided any details concerning your configuration.  Please update your post to include more information, so that we can help you.